# Adding a kill switch to an app

Tags: ios, kill, remote-server

I made an app and have given it to people to beta test and I want to know if people have found a way to get the app to connect to a server then if the server has a certain response the app does something to stop itself from starting next time.

Cheers everyone
Matt

Comment: Be careful with kill switches: in some nations they are illegal.

Comment: This is a private app that only a select number of people will have so I'm not really concerned will that. Thanks anyway though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it in a number of ways, for example through the use of `NSUserDefaults` to set some key to YES once the server had that certain response. `NSUserDefaults` property lists are lightweight and persistent between launches. In your appDelegate you could then find out the value for that key, when the user tries to launch the app again, and if it is set to YES just `exit(0)`.

Comment: So if you put exit(0) in your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions delegate method, the application still launches? Alternatively, you could set a different view controller if that property is set to YES informing the user that the app will not do anything anymore, as it accomplished its goal already.

Comment: Well if it work, go for it, it's just that a value different than 0 in the return value of a process suggests a faulty behaviour, but I guess it's not a big deal!

Answer (score 0):

Sure?  Why not?  You can't insert that functionality into an existing build, of course, but nothing is stopping you from blocking the user while you connect to the server to download (whatever file you want) and analyze it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get it to retrieve a file from a server and check the contents of the file. If it matches an inbuilt key the application exits if it doesn't the app runs as normal.

Comment: So your question is "Is there a way to do X?" and your answer is "I found a way to do it"??  o,0